# You have sent a signed APK or Android App Bundle in debug mode. Sign it in release mode. How to fix it (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, google-play

I have to generate an APK to publish the app in Google Play Store, so I did this steps:

- run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key` and paste the file key.jks inside android/app
- create a file in android folder named `key.properties` with this content:

```
storePassword=myPass
keyPassword=myPass
keyAlias=KEY
storeFile=/app/key.jks
```

- added this code in app/build.gradle:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
```

- Pasted this code in app/build.gradle:

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now,
            // so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

- Run `flutter clean`
- Run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi --release`:

But when I send the apks to google play publish I receive this message:

> You have sent a signed APK or Android App Bundle in debug mode. Sign it in release mode

What I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the duplicate `buildType release`

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now,
            // so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Or rename to `debug`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```